# xpath cant return singleNodeValue

Tags: javascript, xpath

on this page:
https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/category/cat
If you go into the devtools elements page and ctrl+f for this xpath:
`(//div[@id='lhn-accordion']//a[text()='Shop All'])[2]`
it finds one element:
[image]

On the same page, in the devtools console terminal, using javascript I am trying to get this element using the same xpath.
The following code works:

```
document.evaluate("(//div[@id='lhn-accordion']//a[text()='Shop All'])[2]", document,null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

But to get the actual node value I add 'singleNodeValue()' to the end:

```
document.evaluate("(//div[@id='lhn-accordion']//a[text()='Shop All'])[2]", document,null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue()
```

Adding that .singleNodeValue() to the end causes it to fail:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to read the 'singleNodeValue' property from 'XPathResult': The result type is not a single node.
```

Is there something with my javascript syntax that's not correct?

Comment: do you have a specific requirement to use `XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE`?

Answer (score 1):

`.snapshotItem(index)` should be used instead of `.singleNodeValue()` when requesting `XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE`

```
document.evaluate(
 "(//div[@id='lhn-accordion']//a[text()='Shop All'])[2]",
 document,
 null, 
 XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
 null
).snapshotItem(0)
// returns needed Node
// <a href="/shop/en/petcostore/category/cat/cat-toys">Shop All</a>
```

Full docs explaining all result types and how to use them can be found on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Node-Set_Types)